# no keyboard in login page of facebook in WebView

Tags: android, facebook

I have the below code:

```
    mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
    mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    mWebView.loadUrl("http://www.facebook.com/example");
    mWebView.setWebViewClient(new CallBack());
```

When the user is prompted to log in, and the text fields (email address and password) gain focus, the keyboard does not appear, therefore the user cannot log in.

What can I change? The page is loading correctly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this code may help you:

```
webView.requestFocus(View.FOCUS_DOWN);
webView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener()
{
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event)
    {
        switch (event.getAction())
        {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                if (!v.hasFocus())
                {
                    v.requestFocus();
                }
                break;
        }
        return false;
    }
});
```